# accessing data saved in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, filesystems, ios-simulator

I'm working on a game and I'd like to give a non-developer friend a little level editor so they can build levels while I continue working on the development.

I quickly knocked up the following to see if it would create a file my friend could copy and email to me for later use.

```
// Archive Test
        NSMutableDictionary *leveldata = [NSDictionary 
                                          dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          @"This is value 1", @"key1", 
                                          @"This is value 2", @"key2", 
                                          nil];

        NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:gamestate];

        if([myData writeToFile:@"gamestate.bin" atomically:YES]){
            NSLog(@"SAVED");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"FAIL SAVE");
        }
```

According to the log, it's been saved. However, I've no idea where, I assume into the applications tmp or document directory. But is there anyway I can tweak this to make that saved data accessible outside of the simulator, or is there another approach I should take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go into the directory: "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/xxx where xxx is a 36 character unique ID, you will have to find the correct one, I usually just check the modification date.  Be aware of the space characters in the path.